# What is the difference between jest.fn() and jest.spyOn() methods in jest?

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs, spy

I am writing the Unit test cases for my react project and using jest and enzyme for writing test cases. I have read the jest documentation

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname

which explains about `jest.spyOn()` method but I didn't understand completely.

So I want to know more details about the specific places where we should use `jest.fn()` and Where we should/must use `jest.spyOn()`. It would be a great help if can be explained with an example for both methods.

Thanks

Comment: consider accepting an answer or ask for more details if none is sufficient

Answer (score 105):

My simple understanding of these two functions in react/frontend projects is the following:

### `jest.fn()`

- You want to mock a function and really don't care about the original implementation of that function (it will be overridden by `jest.fn()`)
- *Often* you just mock the return value
- This is very helpful if you want to remove dependencies to the backend (e.g. when calling backend API) or third party libraries in your tests
- It is also extremely helpful if you want to make **real** unit tests. You don't care about if certain function that gets called by the unit you test is working properly, because thats not part of it's responsibility.

### `jest.spyOn()`

- The original implementation of the function is relevant for your test, but:

  - You want to add your own implementation just for a specific scenario and then reset it again via `mockRestore()` (if you just use a `jest.spyOn()` without mocking it further it will still call the original function by default)
  - You just want to see if the function was called
  - ...
- I think this is especially helpful for integration tests, but **not** only for them!

(Good blog post: https://medium.com/@rickhanlonii/understanding-jest-mocks-f0046c68e53c)

Comment: It's worth noting that by default, the original method is called when `jest.spyOn()` is used.  See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname.

Answer (score 46):

To my understanding the only difference is that **YOU CAN RESTORE ORIGINAL FUNCTION** with `jest.spyOn` and you can't with `jest.fn`.

Imagine we have some hook that calls a function when component is rendered, here we can just check the function was called, we do not test that function.

Another case if we want original function to test how it works. And we need both in one test file.

Real method:

```
myMethod() {
  return 33;
}
```

With `jest.fn()`

```
const myMethod = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => 25);
const result = myMethod();
expect(result).toBe(25);
```

In case we want to test now real myMethod, we can't restore it back to normal with jest.fn().

Another thing with spies:

```
const spy_myMethod = jest.spyOn(component, "myMethod").mockImplementation(() => 25);
const result = myMethod();
expect(result).toBe(25);
```

And now if we want the original myMethod

```
spy_myMethod.mockRestore();
const result = myMethod();
expect(result).toBe(33);
```

Answer (score 28):

`jest.fn()` it is a method to create a stub, it allows you to track calls, define return values etc...

`jest.spyOn()` came from jasmine, it allows you to convert **an existing method** on an object into a spy, that also allows you to track calls and re-define the original method implementation.

My rule of thumb on this is: if you want to make an existing implementation a spy use `spyOn` if you are building a mock, use `fn()`.